# Receiving 404 error when using next(); with Express 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to add an authentication checker for certain routes on my page via this method:

`node_modules/authCheck.js`

```
var mongo   = require('mongo');
var db      = require('mongojs').connect(mongo.info().address, ['users']);

module.exports = {
   'isLoggedIn': function(req, res, next) {
     function loggedIn(state) {
       res.locals.isLoggedIn = state;
       res.locals.isAdmin    = state;
     }

     if(req.cookies.rememberToken) {
       db.users.find({ 'rememberToken': req.cookies.rememberToken }, function(err, userFound) {
          if (err) {
             loggedIn(false);
             res.redirect('/');
          } else if (userFound.length === 0) {
             loggedIn(false);
             res.redirect('/');
          } else {
            console.log('Found You');
            loggedIn(true);
----->      next();   --- This line causing error at 404
          }

       });
     } else {
        loggedIn(false);
        next();
     }
  }
};
```

My `app.js` has this:

```
var authCheck    = require('authCheck');
var isLoggedIn   = function(req, res, next) {
  authCheck.isLoggedIn(req, res, next);
}

app.use('/tech', isLoggedIn, tech);
```

And `tech.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

/* GET Tech Page */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('tech', { title: 'Tech' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

It works just fine, the only problem is, when authCheck passes and verifies that the user is in fact who they say they are and logged in, it attempts to redirect me to the page requested from the `next();` in this case, `/tech`.

But the page is a 404, as where if I remove `isLoggedIn` check from the `app.use`, I get no 404 when trying to navigate to that page. Suggestions on what is causing this?

Error I'm receiving is:

```
Error: Not Found
    at Layer.app.use.res.render.message [as handle] (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/app.js:48:15)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:240:15)
    at /Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:208:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
    at next (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
    at next (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
    at next (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
    at next (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
    at next (/Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
    at /Users/GacntMac/Documents/Node/SitkaRefrigeration/node_modules/authCheck.js:22:13
```

Which points to `next();` in `authCheck.js`

Comment: Not seeing anything wrong here, what does the `tech` method look like?

Comment: @BarışUşaklı Added for you.

Comment: Does it still give error if you update `tech.js` like this: `router.get('/tech', function(req, res) {
  res.render('tech', { title: 'Tech' });
});`

Comment: can you try making `tech` just like a middleware routine? `module.exports = function techfn(req, res, next) { res.render('tech', { title: 'Tech' }); };`